# Showing a label outside of cell bound

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to show a label between two cells.[image]

But when the cell are drawn the label is cut by the next cell. Only after selecting the cell the full label is shown. Is there any way i could show them all the time ? And what is the best way to approach such requirement if not the uitableview ?

Comment: are you using .xib or storyboard ?

Comment: Please check the size of cell and frame of label

Comment: Yes I am using a .xib and I want the label to be overlapped. It is of-course outside of the cell frame. I need it ti be drawn between cells

Comment: just draw a label in your xib cell and check output

Comment: Label is drawn in the xib cell

Answer (score 2):

Just set the frame of your number accordingly and then you need to disable the property of cell called  `clipToBounds`. You can achieve it both programatically or with code.[image]

Comment: My label is drawn outside but the previous cell is drawn on top of it. They were already clipToBound = NO and cell.layer.masksToBounds = NO;

Comment: Code . The other cell overlaps with the label.

Comment: can u add your tableView delegates methods so i can find what's the issue?

Comment: Anyhow I achieved my requirement by setting cell opeque . Thanks though !

Answer (score 0):

Please check your cell height is greater than the row height.
If row height is small then increase the row height.
It may helps you